# count ellipsis in python

Tags: python, counter

I want to write a programm of counting sentences. The border is (!|.|?|...). The python counts only ! and . and ?. What should I do to count ... too? I tried to write it in usual form but it counts every dot in ellipsis. Please, give me an advice.

```
   f = input ("text") 
   znak = 0 
   for s in f: 
i = s.find('.') 
if i > -1: 
    znak += 1 
else:
    i = s.find('!') 
    if i > -1:
        znak += 1
    else:
        i = s.find('?') 
        if i > -1: 
            znak += 1
        else:
            i = s.find('...')
            if i> -1:
                znak +=1
  print('Предложений:', znak)
```

Comment: Your current code appears to be iterating over the input text one character at a time. A single character will never contain `...`, since that's three characters long. You also have the issue that `...` consists of `.` characters, so you'll end up double counting them unless you take special care.

Comment: You use `else` so this only counts the first item from your list that it finds. Which is a single dot. The rest of your code is never executed. (You also need a loop. Look up how to use `find`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this with `string.count(substring)`:

```
punctuation = ["!", "?", "...", "."]
s = "Hello. World? This is a... Test!"

punc_count = [s.count(i) for i in punctuation]

# Take into account for "." matching multiple times when "..." occours
punc_count[3] -= punc_count[2] * 3

for index, value in enumerate(punc_count):
    print(punctuation[index], "occours", value, "times")

total = sum(punc_count)
print("There are", total, "sentences in the string")
```

#### This outputs:

```
! occours 1 times
? occours 1 times
... occours 1 times
. occours 1 times
There are 4 sentences in the string
```

Comment: OP's own attempt is still salvageable, although (of course) this is the "better" way to do it.

Comment: @usr2564301 I know this isn't the _**best**_ answer, I'm sure this could be done much easier with regex. Sadly my regex-fu isn't the best..But it is much more readable than OP's post.

Comment: No problem, alternatives are always appreciated. It's just that your code is *enitrely* different from OP's  – and it introduces concepts OP may not have yet covered. ...I think a regex could do this but then you can't use list comprehensions.

Comment: Thank You so much! It's really useful!

Comment: No problem. If you have found a solution, please click the check mark next to the answer that you found the most helpful.

Comment: Can you explain this line: punc_count[3] -= punc_count[2] * 3
I don't understand [2] is it the number of index?

Comment: Yes, the numbers in the square brackets are list indexes. It is just subtracting the number of single "." characters (times 3) from the number of times that "..." occoured. (because "." is in "..." 3 times)

Comment: Without that line, it would count "..." as 1 and then 3 more for each "."

Comment: You are welcome! Merry Christmas and Happy New Years!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) like `...|.|!|?` for this, although you have to escape most characters as they have special meaning in a regular expression. Important: The regex has to contain `...` *before* `.`, or it will match `...` as three `.` instead one `...`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "sentence with ! and ? and ... and ."
>>> p = re.compile(r"\.\.\.|\.|\!|\?")
>>> p.findall(s)
['!', '?', '...', '.']
>>> sum(1 for _ in p.finditer(s))
4
```

Or combine with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> Counter({'!': 1, '...': 1, '?': 1, '.': 1})
Counter({'!': 1, '...': 1, '?': 1, '.': 1})
```

Comment: I tried to use regex but failed((( I don't know the python's syntax so good.